# jddayofweek() function is not returning Name of the week

Tags: php

I am trying to get name of the day using **jddayofweek()** it works but It return day in number. so how can I get the name of day ?. thanks.

```
<?php
$d=gregoriantojd(19,02,2015);
echo jddayofweek($jd);
?>
```

Comment: Use `$mode` correctly, thats the second parameter. `1 Returns string containing the day of week (English-Gregorian)  `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the full month name using PHP jdmonthname() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601125/how-to-get-the-full-month-name-using-php-jdmonthname-function)