# How to get the full month name using PHP jdmonthname() function?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the name of the month from a past date using PHP function `jdmonthname()`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$d=gregoriantojd(12,02,2010);
echo jdmonthname($d);
?>
```

It works but it returns month name in number format. How can I get the full name of the month?

Comment: May I know the reason why This post was voted down? I will try to improve this question if something in this post is not according to SO rule. I am new in php and Stackoverflow.thanks

Comment: Read documentation first. [`jdmonthname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdmonthname.php) needs to parameters to work. If you pass only one, you should get warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you have a variable with name $d and you are passing
$jd to the function as parameter and the second is that jdmonthname() takes two parameter...  Now this is the working code.

```
   <?php
   $jd =gregoriantojd(12,02,2010);
   echo jdmonthname($jd,1);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$d=gregoriantojd(12,02,2010);
echo jdmonthname($d, 1);
?>
```

Comment: Hm, a comment added by OPer like "it worked", mark it accepted, and then unaccept it without any further comments about the reason for unaccept ... that's even worse then downvoting with leaving a comment ... Moreover, the now accepted answer only differs from the variable name ... Bizarre! Also interesting: the comment from OPer below the question about "why downvoted?" ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens as you says this is BIZARRE, but at least he solve the problem ;-) This is the life in Stackoverflow :-O

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a second argument to specify the calendar/language.